# How to define unnamed list of items externally

Tags: ansible

Here is a structure of variables I'd like to work with from `packages.yml` file:

```
---
- name: Some description 1,
  package: package1

- name: Some description 1,
  package: package2
```

My expectation was, that I import the file and store the list in the packages variable:

```
- name: Import packages vars
  include_vars:
    file: packages.yml
    name: packages
```

Then I want to print names only:

```
- name: iteration
  debug:
    msg: "name: {{ item.name }}"
  with_items: "{{ packages }}"
```

But get error:

> TASK [Import packages vars]
>   **************************************************** fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"packages": {}},
>   "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "message":
>   "/vagrant/packages.yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash"}

The original purposes I try to get:

1st. Simplify properties definition, by declaring a list of items without a name of this list. I mean, I do not want to define them in external file as:

```
---
- packages:
    - name: Some description 1,
      package: package1

    - name: Some description 1,
      package: package1
```

Although this can be solved easily without include_vars, but via vars_files directive:

```
  vars_files:
    - packages.yml
```

2nd. Having an unnamed list of items in yml file, I want in the playbook itself give it a name. That's what I try to do in the "Import packages vars" task via "`packages`" in the playbook

```
- name: Import packages vars
  include_vars:
    file: packages.yml
    name: packages
```

By this way, I move a responsibility of naming a list, to its consumer. List itself should not worry about how it is named by its clients.

If it is possible, how can I get it done?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the contents of `packages.yml` must be a dictionary or hash, not a list at the top level.

You could assign the list to a placeholder variable within the file and then assign that value to another variable within your playbook using the `set_fact` module.

`packages.yml`:

```
list:
  - name: Some description 1,
    package: package1

  - name: Some description 1,
    package: package2
```

Playbook:

```
- include_vars:
    file: packages.yml
    name: included_vars

- set_fact:
    packages: "{{ include_vars.list }}"
```

Although, given that the file is named `packages.yml`, `packages` would make sense as a top level variable name.